# Issue with Bang & Olufsen speakers on Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: speakers, kubuntu, alsa, pulse-audio

First of all, I am aware that this problem is very widespread and still hasn't been fixed, despite it being *years* old. I am also aware that this question is a duplicate of tens of other questions like this one. And I am not very erudite in the terminology of sound cards and everything.

My machine:

- HP Pavilion cw-1010-ur
- Kubuntu 19.10 64-bit
- Kernel version 5.3.0-29-generic
- AMD processor and integrated GPU

My laptop has built-in B&O (Bang & Olufsen) speakers. **On Windows 10**, even without the auto-installed drivers, **the speakers work as intended** (no static or silent channels or anything). On Kubuntu the speakers don't work at all:

---

Using `pavucontrol` I was able to determine that sound is being sent to the speakers just fine (the volume sliding indicator was changing constantly - a sign of music playing), but the speakers were completely silent. Then I noticed that the speakers port says "Speakers (***unavailable***)". The B&O speakers are not recognized by the system.

---

The sound card chip is ACL295 Analog.

**I want help getting the Kubuntu OS to recognize my B&O speakers**. If you want to send a link to one of the duplicate questions, don't. I have foraged through many such questions on Arch/mint/Ubuntu/Manjaro forums. None of the few solutions listed there worked for me.

Now here is why I started writing this question: I *think* that the issue is not with Kubuntu. It is just that between the Realtek ACL295 chip and the speakers there is actually *a third chip*, most likely of B&O production, that Kubuntu cannot communicate with. Again, I *think* this might be the case. If it is, then there is nothing we can do. If not, and you think you have a solution that might work, then please do share it here.

UPDATE:

I have uncovered some very weird behavior. If I suspend my Kubuntu system, and then wake it, then the speakers work just fine. Some people have reported that speakers work after booting into Windows first and then into Linux, but this hasn't happened to me yet.

What's more interesting is that the Info Center (it has info about devices) doesn't have any record of on-board speakers... But it does have bluetooth radio under Bluetooth Devices for some reason.

Comment: See if [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873881/how-to-install-bang-and-olufsen-audio-drivers-for-hp-laptop) helps.

Comment: Please post the model of the Bang & Olufsen speakers. The model in itself isn't important. What is important is that maybe the speakers have some bluetooth functionality that can be disabled, and then Kubuntu will recognize the speakers as ordinary speakers instead of as a generic bluetooth device.

Comment: @karel, I have not been able to find the exact model, but Kubuntu's Info Center doesn't list built-in speakers anywhere, but it does list bluetooth radio for some reason. I have updated the question.

Comment: @harrymc I have tried that. It didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the speakers have some Bluetooth functionality that can be disabled, and then Kubuntu will recognize the speakers as ordinary speakers instead of as a generic Bluetooth device. As it turns out the Bang & Olufsen speakers are recognized in Kubuntu 19.10's Info Center not as speakers, but as a Bluetooth radio device, and the Info Center has a Bluetooth radio listed under Bluetooth Devices.

In order to disable Bluetooth in Kubuntu 19.10 see the answers to [How can I deactivate Bluetooth on system startup?](https://askubuntu.com/q/67758).

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. I honestly haven't thought that simply disabling Bluetooth would fix the issue; I will try out your solution. Thank you.